# Separate Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

We have 3 apps that we maintain, that all use the same menu controller and Core Data model. In addition, one of the apps uses several views and controllers from one of the apps. It's getting to the point that we need to find some way to separate into different projects to prevent painful Xcode project merges. Right now all the code is mixed in together and each app has its own target in one Xcode project.

Is there any way we can separate the project easily into different projects that have AppA, AppB, and AppC where AppB and AppC depend on AppA?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how each app is different, you can create different targets in your Xcode.

Here's a [docs on how you create Xcode targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html).

If that does not suit your need, you can create multiple projects and reference files from other projects. I really can't tell what you'd need without more information.

Comment: I've just made some minor edits to the question, Is that enough information now?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/).

You can make your own (private) pods for the various files that your projects rely on and then keep them updated in their own repository, and then the projects can include the pod and update it when needed. You can also point specific projects to specific branches of the pod repo etc.

(Not sure whether Core Data is supported in pods yet though, might be)

Comment: I thought about that, but doesn't that mean that every time you add a file to the project, you need to run `pod update` to use the file in your other project?

Comment: Also, are images and xib files included with Cocoapods?

Comment: Re: first question, yea, that's not really that big of an inconvenience. Re: second: images for sure, xib presumably.

Comment: How would I include the resources? I added `s.resources 'Resources/**/*.{jpg, png, xib}'` to it but it didn't add the files to the pod.